# PayPal In-Context Checkout Click Event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, paypal, express-checkout

I am using the PayPal in-context express checkout. Here is what I have at the moment:

```
paypal.checkout.setup("my_app.domain.co.uk", {
    locale: 'en_GB',
    environment: 'production',
    button: 'PayPalSubmit'
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<form id="PayPalForm" action="/lib/paypal/paypal_ec_redirect.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="currencyCodeType" value="GBP" />
    <input type="hidden" name="paymentType" value="Sale" />
    <input type="hidden" name="PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION" value="Sale" />
    <input type="hidden" name="L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0" value="Test" />
    <input type="hidden" name="PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC" value="Test" />
    <input type="hidden" name="L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="NOSHIPPING" value="1">
    <button type="submit" id="PayPalSubmit" class="jfk-button-action">
        Pay with PayPal
    </button>
</form>
<script src="//www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js" async></script>
```

This works at the moment, however I want to add a callback to change something when the user clicks on the pay button i.e. as soon as the PayPal popup window opens. I have tried this:

```
paypal.checkout.setup("my_app.domain.co.uk", {
    locale: 'en_GB',
    environment: 'production',
    button: 'PayPalSubmit',
    click: function () {
        paypal.checkout.initXO();
        $('#popup').html('Processing your booking...');
    }
});
```

This works fine on Google Chrome, however on Firefox and IE the popup window opens and the PayPal loading gif just hangs there with the title of the window about:blank. Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you realy use the PayPal-In-Context-Workflow.
With this script the form is submitted and you reach "/lib/paypal/paypal_ec_redirect.php".
For In-Context-Workflow you first setup your payment and get an token.
Then in the JS has to start flow with "paypal.checkout.startFlow(token)".
Here is a code example i use. The "event.preventDefault();" doesn't execute the form url and ajax is to get the token.

```
        window.paypalCheckoutReady = function () {
        //alert('paypalCheckoutReady');
        paypal.checkout.setup('@Model.PayPalMerchantId', {
            environment: '@Model.PayPalEnvironment',
            click: function (event) {
                //alert('paypalCheckoutClick');
                $('#checkout').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                event.preventDefault();
                paypal.checkout.initXO();
                $.support.cor = true;
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("Checkout","shop")',
                    data: $('#payment-form').serialize(),
                    type: 'POST',
                    async: false,
                    crossDomain: true,
                    success: function (token) {
                        //alert('checkout success: ' + token);
                        //var url = paypal.checkout.urlPrefix + token;
                        paypal.checkout.startFlow(token);
                    },
                    error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        //alert('checkout error: ' + textStatus);
                        paypal.checkout.closeFlow();
                    }
                });
            },
            condition: function () {
                var ispaypal = $('input[name=paymentmethod]:checked', '#payment-form').val() == 'paypal';
                //alert(ispaypal);
                return ispaypal;
            },
            button: ['checkout'],
        });
    }
```

For me